# What does "p is true for S at t" mean?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge, belief, introduction-to-philosophy

In Alvin Goldman's article "What Is Justified Belief", what does "p is true for S at t" mean?
where p is a proposition, S is a person and t is time.

More specifically, how is it different from "p is true"

The full proposal in the article is

> proposition p is self-presenting if and only if: necessarily, for any S and any t, if p is true for S at t, then S believes p at t

[Full article here](http://andrew.cmu.edu/user/kk3n/epistclass/goldmanjust.pdf) (page 92)

Comment: Obviously a proposition and a specific person's JTB knowledge at a time of the said proposition are different...

Comment: crazy question. there are different theories of what truth is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Today is raining" is not true always: at t=monday it is true but at t=tuesday it is false.

Comment: If you read the article, I'm sure he will explain in there what he means. If you did read the article and still don't understand, then you need to clarify your question by telling us what he said that you don't understand.

Comment: If the answer satisfies you, please accept it :-)

Comment: What does ‘self-presenting’ mean in this context? IResearchNet offers, "Self-presentation refers to how people attempt to present themselves to control or shape how others (called the audience) view them." Other sources give similar definitions. It does not mean this, obviously, but what is correct?

Answer (score 1):

'I'm sleepy' is true for me now and not later. 'At t' merely introduces a temporal element in the claim. This statement is now just not a mere proposition,  but a proposition about an event. 'For S' introduces an agent.
If you were to provide the broader text,  the purpose of the text would be made manifest.

Comment: The full proposal in the article is "proposition p is self-presenting if and only if: necessarily, for any S and any t, if p is true for S at t, then S believes p at t"

Full article here : https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/kk3n/epistclass/goldmanjust.pdf (page 92)

Comment: Okay. I downloaded it and while my answer suffices, I'll see if I can't add a little more as to why that particular elocution this week.